# Twilio No Errors shown for Programmable Message

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am following Twilio's API for sending outbound messages. 
I've followed their short code implementation using Nodejs.

Dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "read-excel-file": "^4.0.6",
    "twilio": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

Code

```
const accountSid = '[account sid]';
const authToken = '[account authtoken]';
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);


client.messages.create({
    body: 'Hello from Node',
    from: '[usa number]',
    to: '[singapore number]'
})
.then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

i run the code with `node index.js`

but nothing comes out. I've tried changing vars to const and const to vars but nothing works.

Console shows nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your promise is being rejected, at a .catch, to see what the error is. You can check to see if [SMS Geographic permissions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181108-How-International-SMS-Permissions-work) are set appropriately.

Something like:

```
const accountSid = '[account sid]';
const authToken = '[account authtoken]';
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);


client.messages.create({
    body: 'Hello from Node',
    from: '[usa number]',
    to: '[singapore number]'
})
.then((message) => console.log(message.sid))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: There is a tick on the Singapore option in the settings. 
I get an error like that after trying what you mentioned.

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.twilio.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.twilio.com'
}

Comment: It looks like some type of DNS lookup issue for https://api.twilio.com. Can you resolve that DNS name from the same host running your code?

Comment: Sorry im quite clueless, what do you mean resolve that DNS name from the same host running your code? How can I test that?

Comment: Is the code you wrote running on your local laptop? If so, can you visit the https://api.twilio.com without error? If not, try `ping api.twilio.com` (it wont respond to ping but you should see something like `PING nlb-api-public-c3207ffe0810c880.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (18.208.54.140): 56 data bytes`). DNS is used to map a name to an IP address and it appears there is an issue with that.

Comment: Visiting the website brings me to an XML document tree. 
Pinging api.twilio.com produces "Ping request could not find host api.twilio.com. Please check the name and try again.".

Comment: I am not sure, does the same thing happen running your application from a completely different host with its own Node installation? It sounds like a host specific issue. If it still doesn't work, open a support ticket with Twilio via you Twilio Console or sending an email to help@twilio.com with all the details (or link to this SO Q&A) and your Account SID.

Comment: It seems there could be problems using a Twilio Client with Proxy settings. Had to use Axios or Request library instead with a proxy setting.